# Signalr - Duplicate Hub Names

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Recently started seeing this error in logs on Server Side.  We are using Signalr version 2.2.0.

Any ideas on why this occurs or how to resolve?

> Extended Properties: Exception - System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Duplicate Hub names found.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.AuthorizeRequest(IRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(IDictionary`2
>   environment)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Mapping.MapMiddleware.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.d__5.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: well, uhm, do you have duplicate hub names?

Comment: Did you somehow create the same hub proxy twice on the client side by mistake? Can you show your client code?