# C# SignalR Duplicate Hub names

Tags: c#, winforms, signalr

I've got exactly the same as the question: [Signalr - Duplicate Hub Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39697150/signalr-duplicate-hub-names)
But this doesn't have any precise answer.

What is the possible cause of this issue? I'm sure that I've created the connection once from the client. But when the connection_error raised I reconnect the client manually by calling the new instance of HubConnection.

I cannot reproduce the issue at my local.